# Was a "rebellious son" ever executed?

Tags: kohen-priest, capital-punishment, maseches-sanhedrin, cemetery-grave

The Torah tells us that a rebellious son (בֵּ֚ן סוֹרֵ֣ר וּמוֹרֶ֔ה) must be put to death.   [Deuteronomy 21:18-21]

The Talmud [Sanhedrin 71a] says: "This never happened and never will."  But there is dissenter:

> Rabbi Yonatan said: I saw [such a son] and I sat on his grave.

There are two problems with this statement:

(1) Rabbi Yonatan was a kohen, and so was prohibited from entering a cemetery and touch a grave, much less sit on one.  [Enayim Lamishpat on Sanhedrin 71a]

(2) It is not proper to sit on a grave. [Pischei Teshuvah to Yoreh Deah 364:2]

So what do we conclude?  That at least one such son was executed?  If not, then should we doubt Rabbi Yonatan because of the two problems?

Comment: It's normally improper to sit on a grave because it's disrespectful to the dead. I assume that's why R' Yonatan did it.

Comment: You seem to be asking a different question than the title. Are you asking how he was permitted to do what he did, or are you doubting his account?

Comment: I reworded the questions.  I am really asking what we can conclude from all this.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Chibbah_Yeteirah_on_Torah%2C_Deuteronomy.21.15.2

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9A_%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%99_%D7%AA%D7%A6%D7%90

Comment: A bit of a stretch. Why couldn't Rabbi Yonatan speak clearly instead of using words that contradicted the Sages?

Comment: Some say he meant Avshalom who’s grave he sat on, even though he wasn’t a Ben Sorrer mamash

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/148342?lang=bi

Comment: See the paragraph קבר זמני [here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%AA_%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%A8).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that in Hebrew, על can also mean "next to". (See [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Metzudat_Zion_on_Joshua.22.10.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=he&p2=Joshua.22&lang2=he)).
So Rabbi Yonatan sat near the grave. He used a strong sounding word for emphasis.

Answer (score -1):

Rabeinu Bichaye (Divarim 21:21) says either Rav Yochanan argues on that braisa or it wasn't mamash a ben sorer umoreh like Avshalom.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the questions asked.

Comment: @msh210 i was answering the contradiction between if rav yochanan saw a grave and gemara that says it never happened. Im not sure what the main question is?